# SecurityContext with default System authentication/user

Tags: java, spring, security-context

In my spring application, I would like that a `SecurityContext` always holds an `Authentication`. If it's not a regular `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, it will be a `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken` describing the "system user." This has reasons within different system function which requires a user. To avoid a special treatment if there is no user context, I merely want to add the system context. IMHO, this has also to do with the single responsibility principle.

To achieve this, I can simply implement my own `SecurityContextHolderStrategy` and set the it to the `SecurityContextHolder` with `SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(MyStrategyClassName);`

**Now to the problem:**

The default `SecurityContextHolderStrategy` is the  `ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy`. I'm happy with this strategy and how it works. The only thing which I would change is the `getContext()` method.

```
public SecurityContext getContext() {
    SecurityContext ctx = CONTEXT_HOLDER.get();

    if (ctx == null) {
        ctx = createEmptyContext();
        CONTEXT_HOLDER.set(ctx);
    }
    return ctx;
}
```

to

```
public SecurityContext getContext() {
    SecurityContext ctx = CONTEXT_HOLDER.get();

    if (ctx == null) {
        ctx = createEmptyContext();
        Authentication authentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken("system", null);
        authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
        ctx.setAuthentication(authentication);
        CONTEXT_HOLDER.set(ctx);
    }
    return ctx;
}
```

This is **not** possible as the `ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy` class is **not `public`**. Of course I can simply copy paste the code of the `ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy` into my own `SecurityContextHolderStrategy` and implement the `getContext()` method the way I want. But this gives me the feeling as I might be on the wrong path.

How could I achieve a "system user" `Authentication` as default for a new `SecurityContext`?

**Update**

My approach above is apparently not a solution as it is extremely invasive, creates redundant code and needs special treatment within the web filter chain. But it should give an understanding of my goal. 
I'm looking for a solution, which fits as seamless as possible to the native spring security implementation.
My problem is that I'm quite fixed on the invasive approach. How can this solve nicely? I cannot imagine that I'm the first person with this requirement. Or is the whole concept altogether wrong?

Comment: The association for an Authentication Object to the SecruityContext for a given session is usually done by the Spring Security http filters. If the system user is accessing via a request maybe try an additional authentication filter which configures the Authentication Object appropriately. If not (programmatic etc) it would be much cleaner to look into refactoring uses of where you are using the secruityContext.getAuthenitication() and dealing with the absence in application logic, rather than trying to massage Auth framework behaviour.

Comment: The problem is, that I have scheduled tasks. Those scheduled task will not pass any `HttpSecurity` as they are executed internally. Also the `InheritableThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy` won't do it, as a scheduled task may be instantiated by the system directly after a reboot.

Comment: Also imagine a initial system start up where a few default user records will be created. This also should happen with a system user security context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If got the following solution, which is quite slick and doesn't collide or interfere with anything.
In generall I have two situations where I'll have a `null` authentication:

1. Main system thread.
2. Executing scheduled task. (Could be solved with `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL` config depending on use case, more details see below.)

**Solution to 1.**

This still leaves the problem with the main system thread. This is very easily handled by just setting the context on system start up. Also I configure the `SecurityContextHolder` to use a `InheritableThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy` so all child threads will inherit the `SecurityContext`. We make this setting everytime the application context refreshes. This allows to use `@DirtiesContext` when running security context related tests..

```
@Component
public class SecurityContextConfiguration {

    @EventListener
    public void setupSecurityContext(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new SystemAuthentication());
    }
}
```

**Solution to 2.**

As I have configured the `SecurityContextHolder` with MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL. A scheduled thread will inheriet his parent `Securitycontext`. In my use case this is not wanted as this would mean the following:
If a scheduled task gets initialized dua a user action, it would run under the users `SecurityContext`. As I do not want to loose a scheduled task on system reboot, I'll persist them. Which would lead to that the same task which was before initialized with the users `SecurityContext`, will get intitialize with the systems `SecurityContext` on reboot. This generates an inconsitence. Therefor I configure my scheduler too.

I simply configure the `@Scheduled` annotation to be executed by a `DelegatingSecurityContextScheduledExecutorService` allowing me to set a `SecurityContext`.

```
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class SystemAwareSchedulerConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
    taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    public ScheduledExecutorService taskExecutor() {
    ScheduledExecutorService delegateExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    SecurityContext schedulerContext = createSchedulerSecurityContext();
    return new DelegatingSecurityContextScheduledExecutorService(delegateExecutor, schedulerContext);
    }

    private SecurityContext createSchedulerSecurityContext() {
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
    securityContext.setAuthentication(new SystemAuthentication());
    return securityContext;
    }

}
```

With this two configurations, I'll always will have a SystemUser context if the thread wasn't initialized by the web container.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't sound right to create a populated context within `createEmptyContext()` :o)

As it is stated [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html), "Once the request has been authenticated, *the Authentication will usually be stored* in a thread-local SecurityContext managed by the SecurityContextHolder *by the authentication mechanism which is being used*.", I'd rather extend `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and overwrite `attemptAuthentication` to set the `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken` in case of  a failed username password verification.

**Edit**

I think for system-internal tasks it depends how/by what they are executed.
For `Executor`, there is an [example](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-invoking-a-secured-method-from-a-scheduled-job/) setting up the context as you described above in the thread running these executions:

```
@Bean
public Executor taskExecutor() {
    ScheduledExecutorService delegateExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    SecurityContext schedulerContext = createSchedulerSecurityContext();
    return new DelegatingSecurityContextScheduledExecutorService(delegateExecutor, schedulerContext);
}

private SecurityContext createSchedulerSecurityContext() {
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();

    Authentication authentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken("system", null);
    authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
    context.setAuthentication(authentication);

    return context;
}
```

The `@Configuration` creating this bean implements `SchedulingConfigurer`.

Comment: That's true :) I'm afraid that the idea with the  `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter ` wont work. Imagine  a persistent planned task within the system.  This will be executed from within the system without ever invoking any authentication filter.