# How to get spring cron job executed by user other than the app user of spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks

Is there a way to specify which user should executed the spring cron job set up using `@Scheduled(cron = xxx )`

Comment: Jobs are running in a background thread, so not running as any user, since no Spring `SecurityContext` has been established.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SecurityContext with default System authentication/user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47078381/5221149)

Comment: the job is failing to access a directory on the server, how can i fix the permissions?

Comment: Give the OS user that is running the Spring Boot *process* access to the directory.

Comment: its owned by a different user, I can check.. Thanks.